# Serving a processed template file in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following scenario. I have a template with some placeholders. I also have the data to be filled in, in an yml file. These two come from two different sources. However, I wanted Ansible to process the template i.e., fill in the template file with the contents of yml file and then serve / copy the file to the hosts. Is this possible in Ansible?

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely what the [template](http://docs.ansible.com/template_module.html) module is used for.